# Is there such a distance/metric $\operatorname{dist}_{M}\left(x, C \right)^2:= \| x-\operatorname{proj}_{C}(x)\|_M^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

The typical definition of a distance/metric is
\begin{align}
\operatorname{dist}\left(x, C \right) :=& \| x - \operatorname{proj}_{C}(x) \|_2,
\end{align}
where it is interpreted as the distance of a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to a nonempty closed convex set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

**Question**:

Instead of $L_2$-norm, is there a quadratic distance, that is,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{dist}_M\left(x, C \right)^2 :=& \| x - \operatorname{proj}_{C}(x) \|_M^2 = \left( x - \operatorname{proj}_{C}(x) \right)^T M \left( x - \operatorname{proj}_{C}(x) \right),
\end{align}
where $M$ is some positive (semi)definite matrix?

Comment: What is the nature of the set C? So long as the projection onto C is well behaved, there's no reason your construction wouldn't work. For instance, if C is convex I believe it would work fine.